# Instantiate class symbol using macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm using the following Scala macro (heavily inspired by the code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653447/)) to get a list of all objects contained in a given package that inherit a specific trait:

```
object Macros {
  def allObjects[T <: AnyRef](packageName: String): List[Any] = macro allObjectsImpl[T]

  def allObjectsImpl[T <: AnyRef: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(packageName: c.Expr[String]) = {
    import c.universe._

    val baseTraitSymbol = c.weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol
    val pkg = packageName.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(name: String)) => c.mirror.staticPackage(name)
    }

    val types = pkg.typeSignature.members.collect {
      case moduleSymbol: ModuleSymbol if moduleSymbol.moduleClass.asClass.baseClasses contains baseTraitSymbol => Ident(moduleSymbol)
    }.toList

    val listApply = Select(reify(List).tree, TermName("apply"))
    c.Expr[List[T]](Apply(listApply, types))
  }
}
```

Which works fine.

I want to change the macro so that instead of getting all the *objects* in a package, it gets all the concrete *classes*, and provides a list containing an instance of each of them.

The AST when creating an instance of an Object looks like this:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>u}

scala> u showRaw ( u reify {new Object} )
res42: String = Expr(Apply(Select(New(Ident(java.lang.Object)), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR), List()))
```

So I thought changing my code to this would work:

```
object Macros {
  def allInstances[T <: AnyRef](packageName: String): List[Any] = macro allInstancesImpl[T]

  def allInstancesImpl[T <: AnyRef: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(packageName: c.Expr[String]) = {
    import c.universe._

    val baseTraitSymbol = c.weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol
    val pkg = packageName.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(name: String)) => c.mirror.staticPackage(name)
    }

    def isConcreteChildClass(child: ClassSymbol, base: Symbol) = {
      !child.isAbstract && (child.baseClasses contains base)
    }

    val types = pkg.typeSignature.members.collect {
      case classSymbol: ClassSymbol if isConcreteChildClass(classSymbol, baseTraitSymbol) => {
        Apply(Select(New(Ident(classSymbol.primaryConstructor)), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR), List())
      }
    }.toList

    val listApply = Select(reify(List).tree, TermName("apply"))
    c.Expr[List[T]](Apply(listApply, types))
  }
}
```

However, when I try to use the updated macro code on a test package, I get the following error:

```
scala> Macros.allInstances[AnyRef]("test")
<console>:9: error: class type required but ()test.TestClass found
              Macros.allInstances[AnyRef]("test")
```

From what I'm seeing, it looks like the macro is actually returning the constructor itself instead of returning the instance that should get built by the constructor, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line (reformatted for clarity):

```
Apply(
  Select(New(Ident(classSymbol.primaryConstructor)), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR),
  List()
)
```

You're essentially selecting the constructor twice. You could just drop `primaryConstructor`:

```
Apply(
  Select(New(Ident(classSymbol)), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR),
  List()
)
```

Using `ApplyConstructor` would also work:

```
ApplyConstructor(Ident(classSymbol), Nil)
```

Or you could just go with quasiquotes:

```
q"new ${Ident(classSymbol)}()"
```

The quasiquote solution is the most future-proof.